# du: cannot access file No such file or directory

Tags: bash

I need a push in a bash script to get data from filename but i get an error with `du: cannot access file /home/user/public_html/file.txt No such file or directory`

This is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILENAME=/home/user/public_html/file.txt
SIZE=$(du -sb $FILENAME | awk '{ print $1 }')

if ((SIZE>9000)); then 
    echo "IS OK"; 
else 
    mail -s "IS NOT OK. " user@domain.do < /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: What happens when you do `stat /home/user/public_html/file.txt`

Comment: stat: cannot stat `/home/user/public_html/file.txt': No such file or
directory

Comment: Are you sure the file exists?

Comment: My bad, the file has flie.txt not file.txt. THX A lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, the file has flie.txt not file.txt.